# Why does it not work when I define the range of my while loop with a variable?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm a complete novice at python and am trying to list the first n positive numbers, where n is an inputted value. E.g. when n=5, I want to output 5, 4, 3, 2 and 1.

This is my code which doesn't work:

```
n= int(input("Please enter a number: "))
i=0
while i<n:
    print(n)
    n=n-1
    i=i+1
```

I know I can answer the question  with this code:

```
n= int(input("Please enter a number: "))
i=n
while i>0:
    print(i)
    i=i-1
```

but would like to understand why what I tried at the beginning is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You are decrementing the number and incrementing the counter at the same time.

For example:

| n | i | i<n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | True |
| 4 | 1 | True |
| 3 | 2 | True |
| 2 | 3 | False |

The loop exits once `False` is encountered. To solve this you need to only increment `i` and use `print(n-i)`, keep the `i<n` comparison, *and remove the 'n=n-1' line*

```py
n= int(input("Please enter a number: "))
i=0
while i<n:
    print(n-i)
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, you are decreasing n and increasing i, so at some point the while condition will not satisfy anymore, it has got nothing to do with python.